# JavaScript event.target with If statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why else{} part is not working. and what is the solution.?......... in console.log  'in' is showing, but 'out' is not showing. thanks.

```js
var header = $('header');
header.mouseover(function(event) {
  if ($(event.target).parents('li').attr('rel').length > 0) {
    console.log('in')
  } else {
    console.log('out')
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <ul>
    <li rel="one"> One Element</li>
    <li rel="two"> One Element</li>
    <li> Other Element</li>
    <li> Other Element</li>
    <li> Other Element</li>
    <li> Other Element</li>
  </ul>
</header>
```

Comment: Presumably `$(event.target).parents('li').attr('rel').length` is never not greater than zero. I see no code that would modify that attribute.

Comment: If I hover on li with attributes then console shows 'in' but else part 'out' is not showing.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. It just spews errors because there are no `li` parents, so `attr("rel")` is always undefined. (Not that it makes sense to put `rel` on an `li` in the first place). What sort of a relationship can a list item have? It isn't a link.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way of doing it

The original code.

```
$(event.target).parents('li').attr('rel').length
```

`.parent('li')` is useless, since we are already at the `li` element.

The correct line will be

```
$(event.target).attr('rel').length
```

Secondly `$(event.target).parents('li').attr('rel')` upto this line we will get `undefined` for some `li` elements and `undefined` does not have a `length` property, hence we can use the below `ternary if` condition to check if this element actually exists, then we can return the length property else just `0`

```js
var header = $('header');
header.mouseover(function (event) {
    var elem = $(event.target).attr('rel') ? $(event.target).attr('rel').length : 0;
    if (elem > 0) {
        console.log('in')
    }
    else {
        console.log('out')
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
    <ul>
        <li rel="one"> One Element</li>
        <li rel="two"> One Element</li>
        <li> Other Element</li>
        <li> Other Element</li>
        <li> Other Element</li>
        <li> Other Element</li>
    </ul>
 </header>
```

Comment: @Muhammed Did this answer help you?